# Fragment Debug GPU overdraw

Tags: java, android, fragment, gpu

I have `MainActivity` and added 2 fragments in `R.id.container`.

The `MainActivity` looks like the following.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, Fragment1.newInstance())
                .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, Fragment2.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

`Fragmnet1` and `Fragment2` have the same code with different layouts.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static Fragment1 newInstance() {
        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

And the associated layout `fragment1.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".ui.main.Fragment1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Layout for `Fragment2` is `fragmnet2.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".ui.main.Fragment1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Test2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Debug GPU overdraw `MainActivity` after adding `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`

[image]

See this image below. This is the one more drawing of GPU because the layout in `Fragment1` remains in the `MainActivity`.

[image]

How can I add fragments without loading/showing the fragment below?

Answer (score 2):

You are adding two fragments in the same container. This is the exact behaviour as per your code. If you need to show the fragment added later only, you need to `replace` the fragment instead of `add`.

I do not know the exact use case of yours. However, I guess you are trying to show fragment1 and fragment2 based on some checking. In that case, you might consider having two functions like the following in your `MainActivity`.

```
public boolean fragment1Loaded = false;

public void switchToFrag1() {
    fragment1Loaded = true;

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, Fragment1.newInstance())
            .commit();
}

public void switchToFrag2() {
    fragment1Loaded = false;

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, Fragment2.newInstance())
            .commit();
}
```

Now in the `onCreate` function, you need to call a function based on a condition which is necessary.

```
if (showFirstFragment) switchToFrag1();
else switchToFrag2();
```

You can do the switching whenever necessary from `MainActivity`.

Hope that helps!

**Update**

You can handle the back button click in your `MainActivity` and handle the logic by yourself. Override the `onBackPressed` function and then switch the fragments based on your necessity. For example, see the modified functions above. I am keeping a reference of which fragment is loaded in the screen right now. Then override the `onBackPressed` function like the following.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragment1Loaded) super.onBackPressed();
    else switchToFrag1();
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I need user when pressing back button, the user can see the last fragment, replace function remove the last fragment.

Comment: i need use the add function

Comment: when using onBackPressed because of using the add function, fragment 1 removed and new again, in my fragment maybe have data and this data get from the server. I don't like onCreate() the last fragment, so I want to use the replace function

Comment: I would strongly suggest looking into the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) of Android which can be used to store your data loaded and load back the data again as per your demand. You might consider having a local database setup as well.